# How do I prove this statement about continuity in a metric space?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following statement to prove:

> Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space and let $(p_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $M$, then $$p_n\rightarrow p\in M \Leftrightarrow \forall \,\,\,\text{neighbourhoods}\,\,\, U\ni p \,\,\,\,\,\exists N\in \mathbb{N}:\,\,\forall n\geq N\,\,\,\,p_n\in U$$

**Proof**:

$\Rightarrow$ Let us assume that $p_n\rightarrow p$ and let $U$ be a neighbourhood of $p$. Then there exists a Ball centered at $p$ contained in $U$, i.e. $$\exists \epsilon >0:\,\,\,B_\epsilon(p)=\{y\in M|d(p,y)<\epsilon\}\subset U$$Since $p_n\rightarrow p$ we know that for $\epsilon$ as above there exists $N(\epsilon)$ such that for all $n\geq N(\epsilon)$ we have $$d(p,p_n)<\epsilon$$ Therefore let us define $N:=N(\epsilon)$ then it follows immediately that for all $n\geq N$ we have $$p_n\in B_\epsilon(p)\subset U$$

**Is this correct so far?**

Here on this direction I don't see how to prove this forall $\epsilon$?

$\Leftarrow$ Let us assume that for all neighbourhoods U of p there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that forall $n\geq N$ we have $p_n\in U$. Let $\epsilon>0...$

could someone maybe help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Any open ball with radius $ε$ and center  $p$ is an open neighborhood of $p$

Comment: oh man, thank you very much, but the other direction works.